# Using ng-repeat to create ng-tables which display info from a List

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable

I have a Person object, which has a list of Reports.

```
public class Person
{
    public string IdNum { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Int32 LocFlag { get; set; }
    public IList<Report> Reports { get; set; }
}

public class Report
{
    public long ReportNum { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReceivedDate { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of these people from my controller - vm.Persons and vm.PersonParams.

My intention is to produce a seperate ng-table for each Person, each table should display information from their Reports.

The method I'm using now produces a single empty table:

```
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table ng-table="vm.PersonParams" class="table table-hover">
                                <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
                                    <td data-title="'Report Number'"  >{{row.Reports.ReportNum  }} </td>
                                    <td data-title="'Date'"  >{{row.Reports.ReceivedDate }} </td>
                                    <td data-title="'Subject'" >{{row.Reports.Subject }} </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

Values of Persons and PersonParams:

```
vm.Persons = [{"IdNum ":"23713","LastName ":"Smith","LocFlag":0,"Reports":[{"ReportNum":321231,"ReceivedDate":"2010-09-16T15:25:00","Subject":"Tax",}]},{"IdNum":"32552","LastName":"Xavier","LocFlag":1,"Reports":[{"ReportNum":324342,"ReceivedDate":"2013-09-11T07:50:00","Subject":"Filing Request"}]}];

vm.PersonParams =  {"data":[]};
```

Comment: can you post `vm.Persons` and `vm.PersonParams` values. I mean how these objects are formatted?

Comment: [Documentation](http://ng-table.com/#/loading/overview) says that you have to populate `ng-table` with data created with `NgTableParams()` constructor. By the way, your `vm.PersonParams` is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the total code you are using, then you missed ng-repeat in the outer div. What is $data here? Probably you made a mistake over there too.

You might need to use it as shown below

```
<div class="table-responsive" ng-repeat = "person in vm.Persons">
                            <table  class="table table-hover">
                                <tr ng-repeat="report in person.Reports">
                                    <td data-title="'Report Number'"  >{{report.ReportNum  }} </td>
                                    <td data-title="'Date'"  >{{report.ReceivedDate }} </td>
                                    <td data-title="'Subject'" >{{report.Subject }} </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: He is using `ngTable` and `$data` comes from there. However, your answer is a working workaround.